# Excel index match looking for date, time between time interval returning wrong values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have a worksheet with 2 separate data files loaded into 2 sheets. "EventTime" worksheet contains the Date and the Event Time that a particular event has occurred at.

"Interval" worksheet contains the Date (independent of Date in "EventTime"), Time Start (this is the beginning of a single time interval) and Time End (time start + 30 mins). I aggregate time start and time end into TIME INTERVAL column.

My goal is to determine if Event Time value in "EventTime" falls in between any particular TIME INTERVAL in "Interval" for the same date in "EventTime" and "Interval". The Time Start value cannot be less than Event Time in "EventTime"

I've tried a few index match functions:

```
=INDEX(Interval!$D$2:$D$5322,MATCH(1,IF(EventTime!B2>=LEFT(Interval!$D$2:$D$5322,5)+0,IF(EventTime!B2<RIGHT(Interval!$D$2:$D$5322,5)+0,1),0),0))
```

This maps an Event Time to Time Interval with a rather big violation; it looks for the first time interval that satisfies the condition, regardless of date. So what happens is it looks like the times are matching up fine but if you take a look

The value for 16:28 falls under 16:14 - 16:44 but this violates the requirement that Time Start in "Interval" cannot be less than Time value.

The correct value 16:28 should map to is 16:28 - 16:58

Another approach I have tried is:

```
=INDEX(Interval!$D$2:$D$5322,MATCH(EventTime!B2,LEFT(Interval!$D$2:$D$5322,5)+0))
```

This seems to look at the minute component of Event Time and compares it to the first Time Interval in minutes that the time falls under, how on earth it is picking out minutes has gotten my stumped, it seems to return the correct value for later time periods though, which is very strange.

Method 3:

```
=INDEX(Interval!$D$2:$D$5322,MATCH(1,(EventTime!A2=Interval!$A$2:$A$5322)*(EventTime!B2<=LEFT(Interval!$D$2:$D$5322,5)+0)*(EventTime!B2>RIGHT(Interval!$D$2:$D$5322,5)+0)))
```

I have used Date as a requirement here but now this just matches to 1 time interval only.

Method 4:

```
=INDEX(Interval!$D$2:$D$5322,MATCH(1,IF(A2=Interval!$A$2:$A$5322,IF(EventTime!B2>=LEFT(Interval!$D$2:$D$5322,5)+0,IF(EventTime!B2<RIGHT(Interval!$D$2:$D$5322,5)+0,1),0),0)))
```

Similar to first method I have tried but with added date requirement, gives the same 1 time interval output.

All of these formulas are entered with Control+Shift+Enter.

I have been stuck on this for a few days and it is starting to drive me nuts, I think I'm on the right track but am missing something really simply.

The file is uploaded here

http://www.filedropper.com/example_1

Comment: Is there only 1 possible time interval? Is the matching unique?

Comment: Hello, I've got a 3rd column (city) that will match everything together. I would like to work on the final solution myself so only included date and time interval as the requirements. There should be a one (or many) time events mapping to one time interval. The idea was to capture a single time event in a 30 minute interval, the event can be in between the interval but not before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve the problem with this code, it basically gets the first matching interval time (using ROW($Y$1) for a particular event time based on date and city (city code isnt included here as I've only used date and time as requirement).

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Interval!$D$2:$D$5322,SMALL(IF((EventTime!A2=Interval!$A$2:$A$5322)*(EventTime!B2>=LEFT(Interval!$D$2:$D$5322,5)+0)*(EventTime!B2<RIGHT(Interval!$D$2:$D$5322,5)+0),ROW(Interval!$D$2:$D$5322)-MIN(ROW(Interval!$D$2:$D$5322))+1,""),ROW($Y$1)))," ")
```

This works for my main problem apart from when there are 2 event times very close to each other but get mapped to separate time interval (anecdotal example, event times 14:14 and 14:43, 14:14 would map to 14:14 - 14:44 and 14:43 would map to 14:30 - 15:00). That is fine as this still fits our purposes but I may work some VBA or R to get a tighter event time to interval mapping.

Answer (score 0):

So, um. This got complicated quick but I have a solution, which you might emulate - and then use to further your quest to solve your issue.

I have done one thing, which might make the solution unapplicable to your situation. I have put dates and times together to a single number. In my understanding, you can do this, and then create strings afterwards, but I have no idea what you are using this for so I might be wrong. Also, the interval is assumed to be fixed (at 30 minutes)

This is my formula (keep in mind, that I have added the dates to the times)

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MAX((Interval!B:B)*(Interval!B:B-EventTime!B3-1/48<0)))
```

This will return the "last" viable date and time of an interval that fits the event. Do not get thrown off by the "-1/48" - that is the easiest way to write half an hour in excel time. This is literally the latest interval end that is less than half an hour later than the event.

This produced

```
 Target event    Interval start 
01.11.2015 23:34    01.11.2015 23:23
01.11.2015 22:50    01.11.2015 22:41
01.11.2015 22:48    01.11.2015 22:41
01.11.2015 22:11    01.11.2015 22:00
01.11.2015 22:05    01.11.2015 22:00
01.11.2015 22:07    01.11.2015 22:00
01.11.2015 21:28    01.11.2015 21:28
01.11.2015 21:23    01.11.2015 21:13
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Stian, I'm currently working on another task so do not have the time to try / work on this. Will have time tomorrow so I will work on it then. (I was actually thinking of perhaps concatenating all the requirements into 1 string and then comparing the strings based on time and time interval)